# pushd does not go into specified directory

Tags: bash, shell, directory, pushd

I am trying to go into a directory using `pushd`

```
 #!/bin/bash

 function cloneAll {
   [ -d ~/mapTrials ] || mkdir ~/mapTrials
   pushd '~/mapTrials/'
   echo $(pwd)
   popd
}
```

The `echo $(pwd)` gives me the same working directory that I called the script from.

I read in other SO answers that pushd is only for child processes and that I have to create an alias for it. I have done that also.

I tried doing some commands like `mkdir` to see where it would be created. It is being created in the directory I called the script from and not the directory specified in `pushd`.

How do I get this working? How do I get into a specific directory in a shell script and then do commands inside that directory??

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If _directory_  `~/mapTrials` does not exist and cannot be created `pushd` may fail. (Possible reasons: missing permissions to create dir. or _file_ `~/mapTrials` already existing) Actually, `pushd` prints an error. However, you can check `$?` for result of last command. It is not 0 (in my case 1) if `pushd` failed.

Comment: In the ancient past, we had such strange effects because we used NFS (in a heterogeneous network with SGI/Irix and PC/Linux servers) which sporadically failed to keep mounted network directories in sync. But this should not be an issue anymore now-a-days.

Comment: @Scheff The first line in the function makes sure the directory always exists

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I guess I found the error:

```
pushd '~/MapTrial'
```

The single quotes (as well as double quotes) prevent the expansion of `~`. Move the "snake" out and it should work. E.g.:

```
pushd ~/'MapTrial'
```

or

```
pushd ~/MapTrial
```

Comment: thanks.. `~'/MapTrial'` didnt work but pushd `~/MapTrial` without any quote worked

Comment: @leoOrion You are right. And I thought I got it... - This quoting is really powerful but drives me crazy (sometimes).

Comment: @leoOrion For my luck, I answered `~/'MapTrial'` which I did test before in the bash.

Comment: When I tried it, It gave me no directory exists error